# Error opening Spark 1.5.0

Tags: apache-spark, tar

After downloading the most recent `tar` of `Spark` (1.5.0), I received the following error

```
$ tar -xf spark-1.5.0.tar    
tar: copyfile unpack (spark-1.5.0/python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned/SUCCESS.crc) failed: No such file or directory
```

I tried it a second time and got

```
tar: copyfile unpack (spark-1.5.0/python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned/SUCCESS.crc) failed: File exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`gnu-tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) (`gtar`) instead. [`BSD tar` comes with `gnu-tar`](https://superuser.com/questions/318809/linux-os-x-tar-incompatibility-tarballs-created-on-os-x-give-errors-when-unt#comment342277_318810), or you can install the latest using `homebrew`. GNU tar just seems to be more MacOSX friendly.

```
brew install gnu-tar
gtar -xf spark-1.5.0.tar
```

Comment: Can you add something describing what `gnu-tar` is and how to use it? Homepage? Synopsis?